# Changing symbol's instance

Tags: sketch-app, technique

I have a sidebar in my project with 5 icons and I want to active only one of them in every page.

I defined the sidebar as a symbol. Is there a way to select the active icon in every page? I mean, is it possible to change the icon colors in every instances?

[image: sidebar icons]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You need to **nest** the Symbols.

1. Create 2 states of every icon on the tab bar; Convert them to Symbol;
2. Put them on the tab bar(Whatever the state, you can modify it latter), then create the Symbol.
3. Select the tab bar Symbol, then you can override each icon's states in the properties panel.

*Screenshots to help you understand:*

[image]
[image]